# Accordion Tabs is not working in dotnetnuke

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net, dotnetnuke

We are developing site using dotnetnuke 7.3 version. We are using **Accordion Tabs** module which are free to generate contents tabs of the website. This module is working fine when we are logged in into the admin credentials but whenever we goes logged out it is not working. Means all the three tab contents displayed in the same page and tabs are not working. Can anybody try to give us a solution over it. 
following are the screen shots for better clearity.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you fixed the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that JQuery is loaded. When you are loged in JQuery is always loaded.